# In C code, is there any possible way I could sort the files in directory such that it prints most bytes to the least bytes?

Tags: c, directory

So currently my current code is as so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define sizeFileName 500
#define filesMax 5000

int main( int argc, char ** argv) {
  FILE * fp = popen( "find . -type f", "r");
  char * type = argv[1];
  //printf("%s\n",type);
  int amount = atoi(argv[2]);
  //printf("%d\n",amount);
  char buff[sizeFileName];
  int nFiles = 0;
  char * files[filesMax];
  while(fgets(buff,sizeFileName,fp)) {
    int leng = strlen(buff) - 1;
    if (strncmp(buff + leng - 4, type, 4) == 0){
      files[nFiles] = strndup(buff,leng);
      //printf("\t%s\n", files[nFiles]);
      nFiles ++;
    }
  }
  fclose(fp);
  printf("Found %d files\n", nFiles);

  long long totalBytes = 0;
  struct stat st;
  for(int i = 0;i< nFiles; i ++) {
    if(0!= stat(files[i],&st)){
      perror("stat failed:");
      exit(-1);
    }
    totalBytes += st.st_size;
    printf("%s : %ld\n",files[i],st.st_size);
  }
  printf("Total size: %lld\n", totalBytes);
  // clean up
  for(int i = 0; i < nFiles ; i ++ ) {
    free(files[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output would be:

```
 ./find .txt 5
Found 39 files
./Work/assignment 3/testing/README.txt : 234
./Work/assignment 3/testing/typescript.txt : 30998
./Work/assignment 5/README.txt : 175
./Work/assignment 2/README.txt : 233
./Work/assignment 2/typescript.txt : 18095
./Work/typescript.txt : 12503
./Work/assignment 1/assignment01_test.txt : 3356
./Work/assignment 1/cpsc231_A1_dou.txt : 1807
./.pki/nssdb/pkcs11.txt : 452
./simple.txt : 55
./.cache/tracker/locale-for-miner-user-guides.txt : 11
./.cache/tracker/no-need-mtime-check.txt : 5
./.cache/tracker/locale-for-miner-apps.txt : 11
./.cache/tracker/db-version.txt : 2
./.cache/tracker/first-index.txt : 5
./.cache/tracker/parser-sha1.txt : 40
./.cache/tracker/parser-version.txt : 22
./.cache/tracker/db-locale.txt : 11
./.cache/tracker/last-crawl.txt : 10
./romeo-and-juliet.txt : 178983
./335/335 assign1/script2.txt : 2517
./335/335 assign1/script1.txt : 4543
./335/assign4 folder/script.txt : 42042
./script.txt : 8918
./readme.txt : 3243
./.mozilla/firefox/7rzagn8z.default/AlternateServices.txt : 0
./.mozilla/firefox/7rzagn8z.default/revocations.txt : 43369
./.mozilla/firefox/7rzagn8z.default/TRRBlacklist.txt : 0
./.mozilla/firefox/7rzagn8z.default/serviceworker.txt : 310
./.mozilla/firefox/7rzagn8z.default/SecurityPreloadState.txt : 0
./.mozilla/firefox/7rzagn8z.default/SiteSecurityServiceState.txt : 7776
./.mozilla/firefox/7rzagn8z.default/pkcs11.txt : 890
./.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/log.txt : 1015
./.thunderbird/os4hur49.default/SiteSecurityServiceState.txt : 150
./.thunderbird/os4hur49.default/revocations.txt : 8243
./.thunderbird/os4hur49.default/SecurityPreloadState.txt : 0
./.thunderbird/os4hur49.default/AlternateServices.txt : 0
./Templates/demo.txt : 9
./Templates/typescript.txt : 1549
Total size: 371582
```

Currently my first argument is take in the file type I am looking for while the second argument is suppose to take in the int value of the amount I want. (This is not set up yet in my code however I can take care of that on my own) However as shown in the output, it's all unsorted. I was wondering that is their anyway to print out the contents of `char * files` but in a sorted order from most bytes to least bytes?

Comment: Yes, it can be done. It is fairly straight-forward to sort the files so that they are listed in order biggest to smallest.  There are some trickinesses to do with FIFOs, Unix-domain sockets and other odd-ball file types that you can probably ignore, and you need to decide what to do with symlinks and directories, but the basic process is to read the name and the size from the `stat()` — or `lstat()` — data and sort according to that saved size.

Comment: Note that you have to have a mechanism (probably an array) of some suitable (structure) type to store all the names and sizes before you can sort them into order.  Which platform are you on?  POSIX-like, or Windows, or something else?  The basic POSIX functions to use a `opendir()`, `readdir()` etc; but you'd probably do better using `nftw()` or even `fts` (`fts_open()`, `fts_read()`, etc), perhaps.

Comment: I'm using a Windows by I'm writing my code through Putty via connecting to my universities server, so I'm doing everything through a Linux Unix terminal, if that changes anything.